# brew install dbt-snowflake: /usr/local/Cellar/dbt-snowflake/1.5.1/libexec/bin/pip install -v --no-deps --no-binary :all: --use-feature=no-bina

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, dbt

brew is hanging when installing the dbt-snowflake:

`brew install dbt-snowflake --overwrite -s`

```bash
==> Installing dbt-snowflake from dbt-labs/dbt
==> python3 -m venv /usr/local/Cellar/dbt-snowflake/1.5.1/libexec
==> /usr/local/Cellar/dbt-snowflake/1.5.1/libexec/bin/python -m pip install pip==22.3.1
==> /usr/local/Cellar/dbt-snowflake/1.5.1/libexec/bin/pip install -v --no-deps --no-binary :all: --use-feature=no-bina
==> /usr/local/Cellar/dbt-snowflake/1.5.1/libexec/bin/pip install -v --no-deps --no-binary :all: --use-feature=no-bina
==> /usr/local/Cellar/dbt-snowflake/1.5.1/libexec/bin/pip install -v --no-deps --no-binary :all: --use-feature=no-bina
^C
```

system

```
$brew --version
Homebrew 4.0.23-12-ge986264
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision c78e92f14ff; last commit 2023-02-03)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 8f932465f7; last commit 2023-02-03)

$uname -a
Darwin me-MacBook-Pro.local 22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 21:00:17 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's an option to [install adapters with brew](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/homebrew-install), the [setup page for `dbt-snowflake`](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/snowflake-setup) suggests using `pip`

```
brew uninstall dbt-snowflake
python -m pip install dbt-snowflake
```